# Why is this code incorrect?

Tags: python, syntax-error

I don't know what is wrong with this code. I am getting a syntax error, but I don't know why. Here is the code in Python:

```
1st_miles = 102
```

Need your help.

Comment: because identifiers (including variable names) are not allowed to start with a number/digit - change `1st_miles` to something like `first_miles`

Comment: BTW, in general, if you're going to have a series of variables, it's better to use a list: `miles=[102]`, and then when you have a `2nd_miles`, you can append it, such that `miles=[102, 204]`.

Answer (score 2):

Identifiers in Python can't start with a digit. They must start with a letter or an underscore. E.g.:

```
first_miles = 102
```

Answer (score 1):

Your variables cannot start with a number.

Just try to use the following:

```
first_miles = 102
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you are assigning 1st_miles the value of 102. This is syntactically wrong. In Python the variable (whom to which we assign values) should:

1. Not start with a number.
2. It can start with the alphabet and only underscore(_).

So in order to declare variables, you should start its name with the alphabet, not a digit. Example: first_miles = 102.

Hope this might helps.